# greasemonkey: addEventListener questions

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I've a userscript as the following:

```
document.addEventListener('click', alert('hello monkey'), true);
```

There were two problems:

1. "hello monkey" is alerted only when refreshing the browser, not work when clicking window.
2. using GM's 'manage user script' to edit the script, the change doesn't happen. (The source code on the local disc was changed.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to bind it so it isn't executed automatically...

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(){alert('hello monkey')}, true);
```

Not sure about #2 though.

Comment: Use `function(event)` instead of `function()` to get the event inside the function and possibly target element of the event. See as an example https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/8176-switch-to-mobile-version-on-facebook-video-page